# How can I prevent iframe white flash before loaded content in Shadowbox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, shadowbox

I have setup the shadowbox jquery plugin to launch a gallery which consists of a vimeo file and also some html content in an iframe. The functionality is working fine, but I am experiencing the dreaded white flashes from the iframe before the content is fully loaded.

You can see this in action [here](http://www.zoxfilms.com/final_test/)

Shadowbox does have a built in loading screen, but it is disappearing too early - *before* the content is fully loaded.

I have tried many solutions out there, including [this one](http://css-tricks.com/prevent-white-flash-iframe/) by Chris Coyier, but they are not working for me.

I think there must be a way to do it by using jquery to correct the existing Shadowbox loading screen to wait until content is fully loaded before dissapearing, but I don't know how to do this.

I am currently calling Shadowbox with this code in the head:

```
Shadowbox.init({
    overlayOpacity: 1,
    gallery:        "test",
    continuous:     false,
    counterType:    "default",
    displayNav:     true
});
```

And the markup for the gallery is:
(I don't think it is relevant to the issue here, but for clarity this is part of a custom wordpress theme.)

```
<a class="test" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/43642414 title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" allowTransparency="true" rel="shadowbox[test];player=iframe;width=960;height=540" onclick="return false;" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
<a class="test" rel="shadowbox[test]width=960;height=540" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Credits"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
```

Everything else is done but need to fix this before client signs it off - Any help would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by forcing the loading screen to stay visible through css, then delaying a fadeout to cover any white flashes.

```
Shadowbox.setup("a.test", {
   player:         "iframe",
   overlayOpacity:  1,
   gallery:        "test",
   continuous:     false,
   counterType:    "default",
   displayNav:      true,
   onFinish: function(){
       $('#sb-loading').css({'display': 'block'}).delay(800).fadeOut(600);
   }
```